# Выбор фреймворка для разработки информационной системы с веб-интерфейсом для доступа к базе данных

Tags: c#, база-данных, фреймворк

Подскажите, какую лучше платформу использовать для разработки информационной системы? в качестве языка программирования предполагается использовать С#. Для доступа к БД предполагается использование Web- интерфейса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ASP.NET MVC Framework`